# What causes a SerializationException: "Cache overflow in DataContract"?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

We got a weird error and can't make heads or tails of it, as it is one of a gazillion of serialized calls we do every day without issues for years. Here is the google translation into English of that error message, so the real English message may be worded differently:

> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException: An error
>   occurred while trying to deserialize the message parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/: ExecuteResult. InnerException message 'Internal
>   error occurred. Cache overflow in DataContract. ' was. See
>   InnerException for details. An exception was thrown from the formatter
>   when attempting to deserialize - ->
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: An internal error
>   occurred. Cache overflow in DataContract.

And this is the full stack trace, including the original Japanese message:

```
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException: メッセージ パラメーター http://tempuri.org/:ExecuteResult をシリアル化解除しようとしているときにエラーが発生しました。InnerException メッセージは '内部エラーが発生しました。DataContract のキャッシュ オーバーフローです。' でした。詳細については InnerException を参照してください。 のシリアル化を解除しようとしているときに、フォーマッタから例外がスローされました ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 内部エラーが発生しました。DataContract のキャッシュ オーバーフローです。
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetIdForInitialization(ClassDataContract classContract)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReaderGenerator.CriticalHelper.CreateObject(ClassDataContract classContract)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReaderGenerator.CriticalHelper.GenerateClassReader(ClassDataContract classContract)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatReaderGenerator.GenerateClassReader(ClassDataContract classContract)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.get_XmlFormatReaderDelegate()
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   場所 ReadPFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   場所 ReadAOPFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   場所 ReadAOPFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   場所 ReadOFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   場所 ReadODFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   場所 ReadORFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   場所 System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   場所 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.PartInfo.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlObjectSerializer serializer)
   場所 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   --- 内部例外スタック トレースの終わり ---

Server stack trace:
   場所 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   場所 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   場所 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   場所 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   場所 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
   場所 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   場所 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   場所 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   場所 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   場所 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   場所 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
...
```

What causes it, and how can it be prevented?

N.B. Looking at the source code, such an error is thrown in [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/DataContract.cs,df36fc7233545c43).

Comment: It looks like your particular instance contained nested looping of sorts? have you got the raw payload and model you were trying to deserialize to?

Comment: @zaitsman Wouldn't we see a stack overflow, or at least a huge, repeating stack, then?

Comment: Stack overflow means that there are too many calls on the stack, e.g. a recursion problem when calling method. Here, the error _might_ mean 'you have obj A referencing obj B referencing the same obj A`

Comment: Seems like the exception thrown [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/DataContract.cs,df36fc7233545c43) should only happen when you have tried to serialize too many different **types** rather than too many different objects.  Is there any chance you're serializing run-time-generated types?

Comment: @dbc That's exactly what I just figured - and I'm enquiring.